# Javascript recursive promise stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, promise, infinite-loop, recursive-query, bluebird

I have created a recursive promise function:

```
this.testFunction = Bluebird.method(function (instanceID) {
        var object = this;
        return object.canSsh(instanceID)
        .then(function (sshable) {
            if (sshable) {
                return object.onSshable(instanceID)
                .then(function () {
                    return Bluebird.resolve();
                });
            }
            else {
                return Bluebird.delay((SSH_POLLING_INTERVAL * 1000))
                .then(function () {
                    return object.testFunction(instanceID);
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return Bluebird.reject(err);
        });
    });
```

However, even when `sshable` becomes true, this function keeps recursively going on and on in an infinite loop. I expected that once I return from the `sshable` block, it should exist the function.

Comment: @Adam I should remove the whole then block ?

Comment: Sounds as if `object.onSshable()` would call `testFunction()`. Otherwise, your function should no more be called (but notice that the promises from previous invocations still are being resolved)

Comment: i think it might be resolved now. The function calling testfunction was not handling it as a promise. Could this create an issue?

Comment: Yes, of course that's an issue :-) You always need to treat promises as promises (with `.then` and stuff).

Comment: @Bergi Yes I understood that. However, what happens when I dont handle with a .then ?

Comment: Well, I don't know what exactly you're doing with it. It's just an object with a few methods then. The asynchronous execution happens regardless of whether you attach handler to it or not. If you don't await the result, you might run into issues with the functions that expect the result value. You also might run into timing problems as you're calling the next step too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even when `sshable` becomes true, this function keeps recursively going on and on in an infinite loop.

I cannot reproduce. It seems that something else is calling your your `testFunction`, not the recursive call from that delayed `then` callback.

Regardless, you can heavily simplify your function:

```
this.testFunction = function(instanceID) {
    return this.canSsh(instanceID).then(function(sshable) {
        if (sshable) {
            return this.onSshable(instanceID);
        } else {
            return Bluebird.delay(SSH_POLLING_INTERVAL * 1000)
            .then(this.testFunction.bind(this, instanceID));
        }
    }.bind(this))
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888, not sure why you rolled back your correct edit?

Comment: My computer's graphics card has issues and I lost confidence in the edit.

Comment: @Bergi Could you please explain the bind function? I was not able to follow through from Bluebirds documentation

Comment: @user1692342: In fact this isn't Bluebird's promise `bind`, but the native [`Function` `.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It's just a shorter way of writing what you have achieved with that `object` variable and the closure over `instanceID` in that callback.

Comment: @Bergi Why is there .bind(this) at the end?

Comment: @Bergi will the catch block be after the .bind ?

Comment: @user1692342: As I said, because it's a method of the function (literal). Alternatively, you could make it `.bind(this).then(…)` (and use the promise method)

Comment: @user1692342: No, there will be *no* catch call - that's the simplification. You will put your `.catch(…)` only at the end of the chain, where you call `….testFunction()`.

Comment: @Bergi is there a way to limit the number of times this function is called? Like if this function runs for 10 minutes, then throw an error rather than running infinitely

Comment: @user1692342: Just give it a second parameter next to the `instanceID` that is recursively counting down, and throws an error when reaching `0` while `sshable` is still false.